# Issue with extension method in Kotlin script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying Kotlin script for gradle configuring. Line from `build.gradle.kts`:

```
val deployTest = System.getProperty("deployTest").toBoolean()
```

Running:

```
gradle clean build
```

It works well on my local workstation but fails on TeamCity:

```
IllegalStateException: Error type encountered: [ERROR : Type for (System.getProperty("deployTest") as String).toBoolean()] (DeferredType)
```

Property `deployTest` is not set on my workstation nor on TC. And on my workstation it returns `false`. What's wrong with it?